# Update records in one table for register present in another table, in a comma separated field

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

I have two tables:

FirstTable:

```
code    store  sent
1000002 Store1 0 
1000002 Store2 0
1000002 Store3 0
```

SecondTable:

```
code    stores
1000002 Store1,Store3
```

What I want to do is to update *FirstTable.sent* for an specific code, only for the records present in *SecondTable.stores*

I have a procedure that takes a string and a separator and builds a resultset from the string.
For example if I make the following call:

```
call sp_csv_as_resultset("A,B,C,D", ",");
```

I get the following output as a result set:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I made that procedure while working in the next update statement, which aims to achieve what I need:

```
update FirstTable ft
inner join et_sap_magento_store_ids_removals_IF st
on ft.code = st.code
set ft.sent = 1
and ft.sent = 0
and ft.store in (sp_csv_as_resultset(st.stores, ','));
```

But as you know, you cannot call a stored procedure within a select.

I think a function does not cover my needs either because it cannot return a table or a resultset. Is there a way to do what I need without a design change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a function called [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) that can help.

```
UPDATE FirstTable AS f
JOIN SecondTable AS s
  ON f.code = s.code AND FIND_IN_SET(f.store, stores)
SET f.sent =1
WHERE f.sent = 0;
```

However, be aware that FIND_IN_SET() cannot use an index. In your case, at least the join can use an index on `code` but within those matches it must do a scan the hard way.

There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow about joining on comma-separated strings. I couldn't find one that mentioned an UPDATE query, or else I would have voted to close your question as a duplicate.

The better answer is to avoid storing comma-separated strings when you know you need to reference individual entries in that list in SQL conditions. See my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is an honour get answers from such an experienced engineer. I followed your advise and managed to find a way to do the task avoiding that comma separated field. I accept this answer for encourage me to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do:

```
UPDATE first_table ft
INNER JOIN second_table st
ON ft.code=st.code
AND st.store LIKE CONCAT('%', ft.store ,'%')
SET ft.sent = 1
```